# SQL Server 2008 R2 - Subquery to return range high

Tags: sql-server, subquery

I have two tables. STOCK_HIST contains a time-sequence (DSEQKEY) of values (PRHIGH). The other table (PHASE_KEYS_D) contains beginning and ending keys for STOCK_HIST representing various periods of time in STOCK_HIST marked by PHASE_KEYS_D.BEGKEY through PHASE_KEYS_D.ENDKEY. I am trying to get a query working that will return the highest PRHIGH in STOCK_HIST between the BEGKEY and ENDKEY of each row in PHASE_KEYS_D. I tried the following but it does not always return what it should.

```
select dseqkey,prhigh
from STOCK_HIST
where prhigh in
    (
    select max(prhigh)
    from STOCK_HIST A, PHASE_KEYS_D B
    where a.dseqkey between b.begkey and b.endkey 
    group by b.begkey
    )
order by dseqkey desc


CREATE TABLE STOCK_HIST (DSEQKEY INT, PRHIGH MONEY)
DSEQKEY     PRHIGH
1       1432.22
2       1433.10
3       1435.55
4       1440.21
5       1422.20
6       1415.10
7       1401.99
8       1433.10

CREATE TABLE PHASE_KEYS_D (BEGKEY INT, ENDKEY INT)
BEGKEY      ENDKEY      
1       3
4       5
6       8
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Change the title to something meaningful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of your problems here is that neither table, and especially the PHASE_KEYS_D table, have primary keys.  It's almost always a good idea for all tables to have primary key, and preferably non-intelligent keys (meaning no data is represented in them, they're just dumb ids).

This is how straight forward the query becomes when you have a primary key:

```
alter table phase_keys_id add phase_id int not null identity (1,1)

select p.phase_id,max(h.prhigh)
from
    phase_keys_d p
    inner join stock_hist h on h.DSEQKEY between p.BEGKEY and p.ENDKEY
group by p.phase_id
```

And if you wanted to show the max with each detail row:

```
;with z as (
select h.dseqkey,p.phase_id,h.prhigh
from
    phase_keys_d p
    inner join stock_hist h on h.DSEQKEY between p.BEGKEY and p.ENDKEY
)
select 
    z.dseqkey, z.prhigh, y.mx
from
    z
    inner join (select phase_id,mx=max(prhigh) from z group by phase_id) y 
    on y.phase_id = z.phase_id
```

Comment: sisdog thanks. The second example is very close to what I am looking for. We can consider begkey as the primary key for phase_keys_d and dseqkey as the primary key for stock_hist. I need to return a single row with 3 columns for each begkey in phase_keys_d: 1) the begkey from phase_keys_d (you have this column as phase_id above), 2) the max(stock_hist.prhigh) value and 3) the single dseqkey (stock_hist) in which max(prhigh) occurred. Thanks again for your help.